# Exclude the user on the count if the post is created by the same user

Tags: sql, mariadb-10.3

I have the following scenario in my system:

a member:

```
CREATE TABLE `member` (
  `memberid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` text
);
```

creates the protocols:

```
CREATE TABLE `protocol` (
  `protocolid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdby` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL
) ;
```

member can create a feedback post on the protocols

```
CREATE TABLE `protocolpost` (
  `protocolid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `protocolpostid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdby` text
  ) ;
```

member can reply to the feedback

```
CREATE TABLE `protocolpostcomment` (
  `protocolpostcommentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `protocolpostid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `commentedby` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hasfeedbackreplyviewed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ;
```

I wanted to get the total count of replies from all post comments made on a protocol created by a member, excluding counts of a user who created that protocol, and comments made by the author of the post.

I have written this query so far, but this query returns all the post comments, I wanted to exclude the reply done by the feedback creator.

```
SELECT 
       protocols.*,
       protocolFeedbackReply.*,
       protocolfeedback.*
FROM   protocolpost AS protocolfeedback
       JOIN protocol AS protocols
         ON protocols.protocolid = protocolfeedback.protocolid
       JOIN protocolpostcomment AS protocolFeedbackReply
         ON protocolfeedback.protocolpostid =
            protocolFeedbackReply.protocolpostid
WHERE  protocols.createdby = 1038
       AND protocols.status = "published"
       AND protocolFeedbackReply.hasfeedbackreplyviewed = 0
       AND protocolfeedback.createdby NOT LIKE Concat('%', (SELECT email
                                                            FROM   member
                                                            WHERE
                                               memberid = 1038),
                                               '%');
```

I have attached a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=062e6adf82851a1a85d9a2cc609aeae3) here:

In the dbfiddle example only the comment that is done by the user `nwxaofrc@tempemail.com,`  , should be on the count.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your very good description. Your query is difficult to read and might be simplified if possible. Anyway, within your `NOT LIKE` condition, it seems you need to check `protocolFeedbackReply.commentedby` instead of `protocolfeedback.createdby`, see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=44c51ac63f5a32609d27dcba0f245a87)